# Регeлярные выражения python

Tags: python, re

Всем привет, долго сижу с регулярными выражениями и не могу правильно забрать данные из строки:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
        function init () {
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map("fullmap",
                {
                    center: [53.902496, 27.561481],
                    zoom: 11
                },
                {
                    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
                }
                ),

                                                    myPlacemark0 = new ymaps.Placemark(
                    [53.92095828383601, 27.576141499999988],

                    {
                        balloonContentHeader: 'ул. Куйбышева,69,',
                        balloonContentBody: 'Телефон: +375172433215   ',
                        hintContent: 'ул. Куйбышева,69,'
                    }
                )
                                                myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark(
                    [53.91836478386761, 27.557779500000027],

                    {
                        balloonContentHeader: 'ул. Кропоткина, 72 (ювелирный центр)',
                        balloonContentBody: 'Телефон: +375173342686 ',
                        hintContent: 'ул. Кропоткина, 72 (ювелирный центр)'
                    }
                )
                                                myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark(
                    [53.85993365, 27.673879039987437],

                    {
                        balloonContentHeader: 'пр-т Партизанский, 150А (ТРЦ МОМО)',
                        balloonContentBody: 'Телефон: +375172702356 ',
                        hintContent: 'пр-т Партизанский, 150А (ТРЦ МОМО)'
                    }
                )
                                                myPlacemark3 = new ymaps.Placemark(
                    [53.86173928404149, 27.480183499999995],

                    {
                        balloonContentHeader: 'пр-т Дзержинского, 104 (ТРЦ Титан)',
                        balloonContentBody: 'Телефон: +375173364272 ',
                        hintContent: 'пр-т Дзержинского, 104 (ТРЦ Титан)'
                    }
                )
                                                myPlacemark4 = new ymaps.Placemark(
                    [53.9085033, 27.432121],

                    {
                        balloonContentHeader: 'ул. Притыцкого, 156 (ТРЦ GreenCity)',
                        balloonContentBody: 'Телефон: +375173195722 ',
                        hintContent: 'ул. Притыцкого, 156 (ТРЦ GreenCity)'
                    }
                )
                                                myPlacemark5 = new ymaps.Placemark(
                    [53.93360857063322, 27.652156500000025],

                    {
                        balloonContentHeader: 'ул. П. Мстиславца, 11 (ТРЦ DanaMall)',
                        balloonContentBody: 'Телефон: +375172516899 ',
                        hintContent: 'ул. П. Мстиславца, 11 (ТРЦ DanaMall)'
                    }
                )
                                                myPlacemark6 = new ymaps.Placemark(
                    [53.927029070645496, 27.50984549999993],

                    {
                        balloonContentHeader: 'ул.Тимирязева, 74А (ТРЦ Palazzo)',
                        balloonContentBody: 'Телефон: +375172274279 ',
                        hintContent: 'ул.Тимирязева, 74А (ТРЦ Palazzo)'
                    }
                )
                                                myPlacemark7 = new ymaps.Placemark(
                    [53.96424936324902, 27.624484716156015],

                    {
                        balloonContentHeader: 'Минск МКАД, 50-й километр Минский район, пересечение ул. Мирошниченко (ТРЦ Expobel)',
                        balloonContentBody: 'Телефон: +375172246252 ',
                        hintContent: 'Минск МКАД, 50-й километр Минский район, пересечение ул. Мирошниченко (ТРЦ Expobel)'
                    }
                )
                                                myPlacemark8 = new ymaps.Placemark(
                    [53.890245,  27.554384],

                    {
                        balloonContentHeader: 'ул.Бобруйская, 6 (ТРЦ Galileo)',
                        balloonContentBody: 'Телефон: +375 (17) 224 06 30 ',
                        hintContent: 'ул.Бобруйская, 6 (ТРЦ Galileo)'
                    }
                )
                            myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();
                        myCollection.add(myPlacemark0);
                        myCollection.add(myPlacemark1);
                        myCollection.add(myPlacemark2);
                        myCollection.add(myPlacemark3);
                        myCollection.add(myPlacemark4);
                        myCollection.add(myPlacemark5);
                        myCollection.add(myPlacemark6);
                        myCollection.add(myPlacemark7);
                        myCollection.add(myPlacemark8);
            
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);
        }
```

Необходимо забрать данные точек, которые находятся в квадратных скобках (прим. [53.85993365, 27.673879039987437]). Пытался по разному делать например как:

```
re.findall('^myPlacemark0\s*=\s*new ymaps.Placemark\.$', script.string, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Сами скобки нужны или нет?

Comment: Да я хотел бы сразу получать пару значений в виде списка со списками.

Comment: На данный момент придумал так  re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]", script.string, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
выдает список вида ['53.902496, 27.561481', '53.92095828383601, 27.576141499999988', '53.91836478386761, 27.557779500000027', '53.85993365, 27.673879039987437' и т.д . Не совсем удобно для работы, придется дополнительно группировать, пытаюсь еще сделать что нибудь.

Comment: `x=list(map(eval,re.findall('Placemark\([\n ]*([\[\(0-9\. \,\r]*\])',data)))` для списка списков

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать regEx: `Placemark\(\s*\[(\d+\.?\d+),\s*(\d+\.?\d+)]`

Где:

- `Placemark\(\s*`: текст Placemark( и возможные пробельные символы после него
- `(\d+\.?\d+)`: число вида 53.92095828383601

***Пример:***

```py
import re

s = '...';

coords = re.findall(r'Placemark\(\s*\[(\d+\.?\d+),\s*(\d+\.?\d+)]', s)
print(coords)
```

***stdout:***

```py
[('53.92095828383601', '27.576141499999988'), ('53.91836478386761', '27.557779500000027'), ('53.85993365', '27.673879039987437'), ('53.86173928404149', '27.480183499999995'), ('53.9085033', '27.432121'), ('53.93360857063322', '27.652156500000025'), ('53.927029070645496', '27.50984549999993'), ('53.96424936324902', '27.624484716156015'), ('53.890245', '27.554384')]
```